# How to display a Word document that contains navigation, to SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, word

I have a Word document with navigation and images. I have a requirement to show all the details on a SharePoint page. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online, which already have Office Web Apps implemented, this is quite straight forward. Learning SharePoint wrote the article [SharePoint 2013 – How to Embed a Word document in your Site Page](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/07/17/sharepoint-2013-how-to-embed-a-word-document-in-your-site-page/) which tells you step-by-step how to do:

> 1. Create a new Word document using Office Web Apps from a SharePoint Document library.
> 2. Click on File -> Share.Share -> Embed is available if you are Creating a Document using Office Web Apps.
> 3. Once you click on share you will be presented with a screen that has a Embed Code. Adjust the height and width of the frame and then
>      Copy the Embed code.
> 4. Once done save and close the word document. Next we will add this to a SharePoint page to complete our task.
> 5. Navigate to your SharePoint 2013 site and click on a little settings arrow and then “New Page”.
> 6. Next to embed the code click on “Format Text” tab and the “Edit Source”
> 7. Paste the code that you copied earlier in the source box and click Ok.
> 8. click on “Save and Publish” to see the final out-put.
>
> [image]

Comment: Hi Benny,sorry i got confused with bookmark and navigation bar, i was able to display the word files, but somehow i am unable to show the navigation. is there a work around that ?

Comment: @Rinu Do you want the bookmarks outside of the iFrame, or inside the word document?

Comment: outside will be perfect if the word document will not load each time when you click it

Comment: @Rinu That's harder to come by, and I'm not sure it would work perfect either. Instead, add the bookmarks at the top of you embedded word-document, and it'll display just right in your embedded document.

Comment: but when you scroll down that bookmark will disappear know ?. I am not sure how to do that either can you show me some steps

Comment: or is it display rich text view based on navigation bar click. something like showing a page in content editor or pageviewer based on navigation bar click